# Update database field to -1 of current value

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I haven't been able to come up with a clear answer on this, so I figure before I give up, I could ask here. I'm looking to update a database field to one less than its current value without having to query the database, write code for the math, then update the database with the new value.

Is something like this possible, or would I have to make my own function to do so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
update 'table' set 'field' = 'field' - 1 where 'id' = 2
```

Comment: That was certainly simple enough. Thanks!

Comment: Don't you need backticks instead of single quotes?

Comment: +1. I agree that you should use backticks or plain column names

Comment: @minitech @niktrs The *SQL standard* method to quote identifiers is with a `"` (not a `'`, which is for literals!). MySQL *gets this wrong* and uses `\``. This behavior can be fixed when enabling ANSI_QUOTES. See [8.2 Schema Object Names](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html) for the rules.

Answer (score 0):

Use a simple `UPDATE` statement. For example, if your table was `hello` and your field was `world`, you would do something like this:

```
UPDATE hello SET world = world - 1
```

http://ideone.com/8KIpQ